# Read DevOps Variable as bool in ARM paramters

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to read in a pipeline variable as a bool. I have the following parameters defined in json:

```
"parameters": {
    "disableFunkyFunction": {
      "value": "#{myVariables.disableFunkyFunction}#",
      "type": "bool"
    }...
}
```

In my Azure DevOps release pipeline, I have a pipeline variable called myVariables.disableFunkyFunction and the value for it is set to **true**. However, whenever I try and run the pipeline, it fails on the "Azure resource group deployment" step: *Template parameter 'disableFunkyFunction' was provided an invalid value. Expected a value of type 'Boolean', but received a value of type 'String'.* I have tried using a value of 1 instead, but to no avail.

The following works, but ideally I want to read the value from the DevOps pipeline variable, not hard code it in the parameters file:

```
"parameters": {
    "disableFunkyFunction": {
      "value": true,
      "type": "bool"
    }...
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems that the pipeline variable value hasn't been passed to ARM template file.

Since you have set the parameter value as `#{myVariables.disableFunkyFunction}#`, you can try to use the Replace Token task from [Replace Tokens Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens).

Here are the steps:

Step1: Keep the parameter value as `#{myVariables.disableFunkyFunction}#`.

Step2: Use Replace token task to set the value.

Step3: Deploy the ARM template.

For example:

[image]

**Note:** You need to put the Replace token task before the ARM template deployment step.